# Unable to filter Json array to Show in tableview in swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, filter

Json response like this

```
{
"categories": [
    {
        "id": 48,
   
        "products": [
            {
                "name": ".Tea",
                "food_type": "veg",
```

**Code:** with this code i am able to show all first category products in tableview.. here if i click `vegSwitch` i need to show only `"food_type": "veg"` related products in tableview

```
 class FoodsMenuVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var vegSwitch: UISwitch!
var foodType: String = ""
var filterArray: : Category?
var categoryArray: Category?
private var catData: Categories? {
    didSet{
     
        categoryArray = catData?.categories?[0]

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    foodMenuServicecall()
}

@IBAction func vegSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    
    if sender.isOn{
        filterArray = categoryArray?.products?.filter { $0.foodType?.rawValue == "veg" }
    }
    else{
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categoryArray?.products?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FoodIteamsCell", for: indexPath) as! FoodIteamsCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    
    if let eachCat = categoryArray{
        
        cell.nameLbl.text = eachCat.products?[indexPath.row].name?.capitalized
        
        for oneImg in eachCat.products?[indexPath.row].images ?? []{
            cell.iteamImg.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: oneImg.url ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
        }
    }
    return cell
}
}
```

**if i try like this in vegSwitch button `filterArray = categoryArray?.products?.filter { $0.foodType?.rawValue == "veg" }`**

error:

> Cannot assign value of type '[Product]?' to type 'Category?'

please guide me to filter JSON

Comment: You are filtering category?.products which returns an array of products which is of type [Product]?. This cannot be assigned to filterArray since its type is Category?.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze:

You have:

```
var filterArray: : Category?
var categoryArray: Category?
```

Then, you do:

```
filterArray = categoryArray?.products?.filter { $0.foodType?.rawValue == "veg" }
```

Which is equivalent, once "broken into multiple statements":

```
let products: [Product]? = categoryArray?.products
let filtered: [Product] = products?.filter { $0.foodType?.rawValue == "veg" }
filterArray = filtered //Here it fails, because `filterArray` is a Category and filtered a `[Product]`
```

So the solution would be to have extra method to Category:

```
extension Category {
    static func make(fromCategory category: Category, withProducts products: [Product]) -> Category {
        return Category(id: category.id, products: products)
    }
}
```

I use only `id` & `products` properties, since I don't know if there are more, but add them if needed.

Then, now, you can construct a `Category` that you can build from existing Category & filtered products.

In use:

```
let filterArray = categoryArray.compactMap { aCategory -> Category? in
    let filteredProducts = aCategory.products.filter { $0.foodType == "veg" }
    if filteredProducts.isEmpty {
        return nil // or Category.make(fromCategory: aCategory, withProducts: []), or just ignore the if test if it's fine to have a section category without products
    }
    return Category.make(fromCategory: aCategory, withProducts: filteredProducts)
}
```

But, according to your code, you don't seem to use Category, so get rid of it, and just use an array of products directly.

Comment: cant we do filter without using `extension Category`... i am learnig swift codes.. for me above code is hard to understand... could you make it easy please... with that extension  i donno how to show tableview

Comment: Put `make(fromCategory:withProduct)` inside `struct Category`, there is not need for a category in reality.

Comment: in my code how to do filter with `food_type` for products in categories.. and show in tableview

Comment: I've shown how to replace `filterArray = categoryArray?.products?.filter { $0.foodType?.rawValue == "veg" }` with `let filterArray = categoryArray.compactMap `, it doesn't work?

Comment: i couldn't understand where to replace

Comment: You wrote `filterArray = categoryArray?.products?.filter { ... }`,  just write instead  `filterArray = categoryArray.compactMap { ... }`

Comment: `filterArray = categoryArray?.products?.compactMap { $0.foodType?.rawValue == "veg" }`... i tried like this in `vegSwitch ` then error

`Cannot assign value of type '[Bool]?' to type 'Category?'`

Comment: Sorry. I fixed my answer. It's just that `filteredArray` and `categoryArray` names are misleading since they aren't arrays...